# MySQL not using an index when using SELECT *

Tags: sql, mysql, performance, query-optimization

I'm having some trouble adding a new index to my table and I'm wondering why MySQL isn't using the new index.

I noticed that it only happens when my SELECT statement requests other colums which aren't part of the index (e.g. `SELECT *` doesn't work while `SELECT id, otherId` does work).

Can someone explain to me why MySQL chooses to do a table scan instead of using the index?

### Database schema

The table consists of multiple columns, namely `id` and `otherId`. `id` is my primary key while `otherId` should get indexed as well. `otherId` can be null and is unique.

```
model Entity {
    id      String  @id @default(cuid())
    otherId String? @unique
    // Few more ...
}
```

### Cardinality and selectivity

```sql
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT Entity.otherId) as cardinality,
  COUNT(*) as totalRows,
  COUNT(Entity.otherId) as nonNullRows,
  COUNT(DISTINCT Entity.otherId) / COUNT(*) as selectivity
FROM
  Entity
```

| cardinality | totalRows | nonNullRows | selectivity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 171 | 1187 | 171 | 0.1441 |

### EXPLAIN SELECT *

This one doesn't use the index but I wish it would.

```sql
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM Entity WHERE Entity.otherId = ?;
```

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | Entity |  | ALL | Entity_otherId_key |  |  |  | 1187 | 10 | Using where |

### EXPLAIN SELECT id, otherId

This one does use the index.

```sql
EXPLAIN SELECT id, otherId FROM Entity WHERE Entity.otherId = ?;
```

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | Entity |  | index | Entity_otherId_key | Entity_otherId_key | 767 |  | 1187 | 10 | Using where; Using index |

### SHOW INDEXES

```sql
SHOW INDEXES from Entity;
```

| Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Entity | 0 | PRIMARY | 1 | id | A | 1187 |  |  |  | BTREE |  |  | YES |  |
| Entity | 0 | Entity_otherId_key | 1 | otherId | A | 172 |  |  | YES | BTREE |  |  | YES |  |

### MySQL version

8.2.0

Comment: Can you please run the query `SELECT VERSION();` and report what it says?

Comment: Are you sure the EXPLAIN says `type: ALL` in the second query? I would expect it to say `type: index`, unless they've changed the implementation of EXPLAIN reports.

Comment: @BillKarwin I'm using MySQL 8.2.0.

Comment: @BillKarwin You are right, I copied that wrongly. It says type: index. The other parts are correct.,

Comment: What percentage of the rows have the desired value for otherId ?

Comment: @RickJames One as it is unique. However, it's nullable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77819940/mysql-not-using-an-index-when-using-select?noredirect=1#comment137192006_77820435

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a query does no row restriction (WHERE clause) or sorting (ORDER BY clause), it is bound to examine every row.

This is supported by the `rows` column of the two EXPLAIN results. It show 1187 even in the second example.

But what's the difference between `type: ALL` and `type: index`?

The first is a table-scan. The query will examine every row in the table. It must do this to count them, because of MVCC. Thus the cost of the query is directly proportional to the number of rows.

The second is an index-scan. This is slightly better than a table-scan, but it still needs to examine every entry in the named index to count them. The cost is also directly proportional to the number of rows, but it may be able to examine fewer pages to read the index alone instead of the whole table.

The note in the EXPLAIN "Using index" leads you to believe it's optimized. Strictly speaking it's true that it's using an index for this query, but it's not using the index in the same way that it would for searching or sorting.

---

In cases where a query *might* use an index for a row restriction, the optimizer may choose not to do so. A common case is that the specific value you search for is estimated to occur on a large proportion of rows. The optimizer decides that doing an index lookup for that value and then a second lookup to get the row is likely to be more costly than just doing the table-scan, as if no index were present.

We can think of the index at the back of a book. Why are common words not indexed? Because it would be needless overhead to look up a common word that occurs on many pages. It's just as much work (i.e. turning pages of the book) to read the book cover-to-cover.

In the case of MySQL's optimizer, if the optimizer thinks the value you search for occurs on about 20% of the rows of the table, then it is likely to skip the index. This threshold is not documented, and may be affected by other optimizer analysis. It's just a rough threshold I've observed.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, I don't understand "Neither of your queries do any row restriction (WHERE clause)" since I do have a WHERE clause in which I look for a specific id. -> `WHERE Entity.otherId = ?;`

Comment: Apologies. I've edited my answer above to correct that and cover the case of a WHERE clause.

Comment: The index on otherId is unique. However, it's also nullable. Currently about 85% are null. Does the optimizer treat null like any other non-null/actual value? If so, that would make sense considering your explanation "if the optimizer thinks the value you search for occurs on about 20% of the rows of the table".

Comment: NULL is treated as a value for purposes of the optimizer's choice of index, but you can't search for NULL using the `=` operator. You must use `<column> IS NULL`.